# How can those two SQL statements be combined into one?

Tags: mysql, sql, mariadb

I wrote and would like to combine these 2 sql, one is based on results of another. I checked [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2317686/joining-2-sql-select-result-sets-into-one), but looks like its not results based. How could I achieve it ?

First sql:

```
SELECT
    `potential`.*,
    `customer`.`ID` as 'FID_customer'
FROM
    `os_potential` as `potential`,
    `os_customer` as `customer`
WHERE `potential`.`FID_author` = :randomID
      AND `potential`.`converted` = 1
      AND `potential`.`street` = `customer`.`street`
      AND `potential`.`zip` = `customer`.`zip`
      AND `potential`.`city` = `customer`.`city`;
```

Second sql:

```
SELECT
    sum(`order`.`price_customer`) as 'Summe'
FROM
    `os_order` as `order`,
    `RESUTS_FROM_PREVIOUS_SQL_STATEMENT` as `results`
WHERE `order`.`FID_status` = 10
      AND `results`.`FID_customer` = `order`.`FID_customer`;
```

I would like to get everything from first sql + the 'Summe' from second sql.

**TABLES**

1.Potentials:

```
+----+------------+-----------+--------+-----+------+
| ID | FID_author | converted | street | zip | city |
+----+------------+-----------+--------+-----+------+
```

2.Customers:

```
+----+--------+-----+------+
| ID | street | zip | city |
+----+--------+-----+------+
```

3.Orders:

```
+----+--------------+----------------+
| ID | FID_customer | price_customer |
+----+--------------+----------------+
```

Comment: It is very hard to answer your question without knowing structure of your DB and relationship between tables. Can you shed a light on it?

Comment: Seems you may need a subquery. Use the *results from another query* that will needed to behave like a table as a subquery to the query that needs them as a table.

Comment: @AndyKorneyev I edited my post and shown tables below my queries.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
SELECT p.*
     , c.ID FID_customer
     , o.summe
  FROM os_potential p
  JOIN os_customer c
    ON c.street = p.street 
   AND c.zip = p.zip 
   AND c.city = p.city 
  JOIN 
     ( SELECT FID_customer
            , SUM(price_customer) Summe
         FROM os_order 
        WHERE FID_status = 10
        GROUP
           BY FID_customer
     ) o
    ON o.FID_customer = c.ID
 WHERE p.FID_author = :randomID 
   AND p.converted = 1
   ;
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. It does exactly what I need. Could you please explain a little bit how it works?

Comment: I took the second query, and stuck it inside the first query. It's called an uncorrelated subquery.

Answer (score 2):

You would just write a single query like this:

```
SELECT sum(o.price_customer) as Summe
FROM os_order o JOIN
     os_potential p JOIN
     os_customer c
     ON p.street = c.street AND p.zip = c.zip AND p.city = c.city JOIN
     os_order o2
     ON o2.FID_customer = c.FID_customer
WHERE p.FID_author = :randomID AND p.converted = 1 AND
      o2.FID_status = 10 ;
```

Notes:

- *Never* use commas in the `FROM` clause.  *Always* use explicit `JOIN` syntax with conditions in an `ON` clause.
- Table aliases are easier to follow when they are short.  Abbreviations for the table names is commonly used.
- Backticks are only necessary when the table/column name needs to be escaped.  Yours don't need to be escaped.

Comment: `order` is a reserved word (order by), that must be enclosed by backticks in the original query

Comment: @Shadow While I agree that `order` is a poor choice for a table/column name, it doesn't need backticks in this particular context. That said, I'm not convinced that this is what the OP is looking for.

Comment: There is TYPO in last JOIN os.order should be os_order, I get error `Not unique table/alias: 'o'`, when I fix it, there is uknown column 'c.FID_customer', should be c.ID. When I fix all those. I get 1 column and 1 row with huge number. Since I am really beginner, I dont even know where it comes from. But thanks a lot for the notes. I'm willing to learn joints and good sql practices!

Answer (score 1):

If the 1st query return 1 record per customer, then just simply join the 3 tables, keep the sum and use the `group by` clause:

```
SELECT
    `potential`.*,
    `customer`.`ID` as 'FID_customer',
    sum(`order`.`price_customer`) as Summe
FROM
    `os_potential` as `potential`
INNER JOIN
    `os_customer` as `customer`
ON  `potential`.`street` = `customer`.`street`
      AND `potential`.`zip` = `customer`.`zip`
      AND `potential`.`city` = `customer`.`city`
LEFT JOIN
    `os_order` as `order`
ON  `results`.`FID_customer` = `order`.`FID_customer`
      AND `order`.`FID_status` = 10
WHERE `potential`.`FID_author` = :randomID
      AND `potential`.`converted` = 1
GROUP BY `customer`.`ID`, <list all fields from potential table>
```

If the 1st query may return multiple records per customer, then you need to do the summing in a subquery:

```
SELECT
    `potential`.*,
    `customer`.`ID` as 'FID_customer',
    `order`.Summe
FROM
    `os_potential` as `potential`
INNER JOIN
    `os_customer` as `customer`
ON  `potential`.`street` = `customer`.`street`
      AND `potential`.`zip` = `customer`.`zip`
      AND `potential`.`city` = `customer`.`city`
LEFT JOIN
    (SELECT FID_customer, sum(price_customer) as Summe
     FROM `os_order`
     WHERE FID_status=10 
     GROUP BY FID_customer
    ) as `order`
ON  `results`.`FID_customer` = `order`.`FID_customer`
WHERE `potential`.`FID_author` = :randomID
      AND `potential`.`converted` = 1
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you should use a subselect, but be careful with the number of results, it's not the best for performance.

You can do something like this:

```
SELECT n1, n2, (select count(1) from whatever_table) as n3, n4 from whatever_table
```

note that the subselect must return just 1 result, in other case you'll have an error