# Why my query shows no errors, but also returns zero rows?

Tags: mysql, sql, mariadb

I have written this query to get as many rows as there are users + count of potentials that each user have created + all potentials that have been converted. This is how it looks like:

```
SELECT u.*, p.allPotentials, pc.cPotentials 
   FROM os_user u
JOIN (SELECT FID_author, count(*) allPotentials FROM os_potential) p 
   ON p.FID_author = u.ID 
JOIN (SELECT converted, FID_author, count(*) cPotentials FROM os_potential) pc 
   ON p.FID_author = u.ID AND pc.converted = 1
```

I am trying to do it with *uncorrelated subquery* as [this answer explained me](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39349349/6374837), that I can combine my queries into 1. But im getting 0 rows.

My tables looks like this:

Users:

```
+----+------+-------+
| ID | Name | Email |
+----+------+-------+
```

Potentials:

```
+----+------+-------+------------+-----------+
| ID | Name | Email | FID_author | converted |
+----+------+-------+------------+-----------+
```

FID_author is foreign key, the user id.

My query is returning 0 rows and shows no errors. What am I doing wrong?

**EDIT**

So far my query:

```
SELECT u.*, p.allPotentials, pc.cPotentials 
   FROM os_user u
LEFT JOIN (SELECT FID_author, count(*) allPotentials 
   FROM os_potential GROUP BY FID_author) p 
   ON p.FID_author = u.ID 
LEFT JOIN (SELECT converted, FID_author, count(*) cPotentials 
   FROM os_potential GROUP BY FID_author) pc 
   ON p.FID_author = u.ID 
   AND pc.converted = 1 
GROUP BY u.ID
```

I am getting results almost as expected, but the problem is, `cPotentials` contains 1 in every row, which is false. There are much many then only 1. Where could be the problem?

Comment: Missing GROUP BY's in the sub-queries.

Comment: Thanks for fast comment, I just added `GROUP BY FID_author` to the end of my each subquery, but it still returns 0 rows.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Missing group by  on subquery and eventully use left join

```
SELECT u.*, p.allPotentials, pc.cPotentials 
 FROM os_user u
LEFT JOIN (SELECT FID_author, count(*) allPotentials FROM os_potential 
                  GROUP BY FID_author) p 
 ON p.FID_author = u.ID 
LEFT JOIN (SELECT converted, FID_author, count(*) cPotentials FROM os_potential 
                   GROUP BY converted,FID_author) pc 
 ON pc.FID_author = u.ID AND pc.converted = 1
```

Comment: It gave me right direction to make my query work. However, I had to `GROUP BY u.ID` the main query also. Now I just need to read more about `GROUP BY` and all possible `JOIN`'s and how they works. Thanks for fast answer.

Comment: @ksno   .. in main query i don't see aggregation function so you don't should need group by  .. eventually you need distinct for retrieve distinct value  ..